# Docker container log files are lost after every deploy from Gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab

Everytime is run a Pipline, the gitlab runner will create a new docker contrainer, the log files from the lastly created docker will be lost!
I want to keep a log history for 3 Monthes at minimum.

I don't want to lose the logs of my docker container after every delpoy from gitlab runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they are not lost, all logs can be found here `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/<container_id>-json.log`. No need to blame gitlab runner for that, it just creates new container for you. If you want to keep history of logs, it will be wise to store them somewhere else. For example very popular solution will be use [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack)

Comment: Can man save these logs to a volume?

Comment: Sure, you can, you can use existing solution like [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-container.html) or write something by yourself

Comment: Or do you mean docker persistent volume? If you want to collect logs in your docker volume then you need to change your logging library and make it write logs to a file located in connected volume. (But I'd recommend using standard output and filebeat with elk - this is very popular solution that save your time)